# CAST AS DATE Returns in NVARCHAR Format

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, nvarchar

`CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` returns in `NVARCHAR(10)`. `DATETIME` changes the column to a date, but I don't want the time in it. I want a DATE formatted column that just contains the date. What am I missing?

Comment: `cast(getdate() as date)` should be doing what you want.  Please explain how it is not working.

Comment: you should also explain why you think it is VNVARCHAR(10) -- what front end are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL DBX as my front end. The column types are returned under the column names and displays as NVARCHAR(10).

Comment: No it does not. Cast (getdate() as date) returns a date. If you believe it it returned as nvarchar(10) then there is someting else affecting that value. Or, you are confusing what you see (the default date display format) with the underlying data type.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Date_Issue]

So apparently it is storing the value with date, it just shows the wrong type on the returned results. If you can see the image, It shows it as Date in two other places, but in the bottom section you can see where it shows as NVARCHAR. I'm not sure why it does that, probably something to do with SQL DBX. Either way, sorry for wasting everyone's time. I've just never seen it display the wrong type in the returned results.

Answer (score 0):

As a way to demonstrate that cast(getdate() as date) does return the *data type* of **date**

```
select
   cast(getdate() as date) cast_getdate
into MyTable_x
;

select
  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'MyTable_x'
;


+------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME  | ORDINAL_POSITION | DATA_TYPE |
+------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+
| MyTable_x  | cast_getdate |                1 | date      |
+------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you need to change the datatype of the column.  Try this:

ALTER TABLE [Table Name]
ALTER COLUMN [Column Name] DATE

Comment: His question is about the GETDATE() function -- that is not a column.

Comment: I get that, but his question wasn't clear.  Since CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) doesn't return the time, I'm guessing he meant the column in the table still had the time, hence my response.

Comment: What column? What table?  Neither of these things are mentioned in the question.  He is clearly asking how to get the current date and return it formatted.  This has nothing to do with a table or column in his database.

Comment: Again, his question wasn't clear.  I was taking an educated guess.